# Search results doesn't show with Turkish characters

Tags: characters

my problem is this.

There are posts with string "ÖZYALIN"

When I search it as ÖZYALIN results appear without any issue. But when I do that search as Özyalın or özyalın results doesn't show.

It doesn't happen when string doesn't have any unique Turkish character. Forexample if you search for sting MAYAN you can use MAYAN, Mayan or mayan and results appear without and issue.

Comment: We cannot reproduce the issue: http://prntscr.com/u0cs4a. Requesting to debug yourself with the guide available here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info

Answer (score 0):

I am just wondering if your website language (in backend) is set to ISO 8859-9 ("Latin 5").

You can manualy check and set them inside wp-config.php or if you go into settings->general
https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/?p=1480

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @Papalino, sorry to hear that. It was worth a try. Also are you using some other plugin for search, or some other graphic content editor like (Divi, Elementor). it can be something in there to try and configure.
Best of luck ;)